# Distributions with a given mean and covariance

Tags: probability, geometry, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Fix $X := \mathbb R^d$ for some $d \ge 1$. Fix a vector $m \in X$ and a  covariance operator $k : X^* \to X$, i.e., a symmetric, nonnegative-definite operator.

Let $\Delta_{m,k}(X)$ denote the probability measures on $X$ with mean $m$ and covariance $k$. There is (at least) one notable measure in this class: the Gaussian $\mathbb G_{m,k}$ with mean $m$ and covariance $k$.

Some basic questions:

- Are there any other notable measures in $\Delta_{m,k}$(X)$?
- Is every measure in $\Delta_{m,k}(X)$ absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathbb G_{m,k}$? If so, $\Delta_{m,k}(X)$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L^1(X,\mathbb G_{m,k})$. Does that subspace have certain nice properties?
- If $(m', k')$ are another mean-and-covariance pair, how are the spaces $\Delta_{m,k}(X)$ and $\Delta_{m',k'}(X)$ related to each other?